# how to use session variables in email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, session, session-variables

The Title does not make brilliant sense but essentially I want to use session variables and include them within an email body within the c# code. Sending the email without session variables works fine. Is it even possible to do what I want?

REVISED CODE:

```
public partial class Success : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser userName = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

        ListBox order = (ListBox)(Session["order"]);

        string name = (String)(Session["name"]);
        string addressLine1 = (String)(Session["addressLine1"]);
        string addressLine2 = (String)(Session["addressLine2"]);
        string addressLine3 = (String)(Session["addressLine3"]);
        string county = (String)(Session["county"]);
        string postCode = (String)(Session["postcode"]);

        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("my email");
        mail.To.Add("recipient email");
        mail.Subject = "Your Reciept";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        string htmlBody;
        htmlBody = "Hi "+ userName + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Here's your details: " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
                    + order + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
                    + name + Environment.NewLine
                    + addressLine1 + Environment.NewLine
                    + addressLine2 + Environment.NewLine
                    + addressLine3 + Environment.NewLine
                    + county + Environment.NewLine
                    + postCode + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        mail.Body = htmlBody;
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my email", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

also to note, `Environment.NewLine` does not work. 
Your help would be most appreciated

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil the problem is that the session variables I want to use do not appear on the email

Comment: I looks to me like you're getting the values from session correctly. Are you sure they're not null after getting them?

Comment: Instead of `Environment.NewLine`, use `<br />` (HTML line breaks) since you are doing an HTML email instead of plain text.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil sorry for wasting your time but I figured out a solution (See my answer). You were right in saying that they were null after getting them as I never set them in the first place. Thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who helped me, sorry for wasting your time. I figured it out... really stupid but I was setting the session variables incorrectly in a previous webform before therefore the session variables were null.

the reason that there was no error was (my guess), I was setting the session variables on button_click function yet also having a postbackurl. the postbackurl must have overridden the button_click function.

So, For future reference. Originally I had

```
string name = Session["name"].ToString();
lblName.Text = name; //this didnt work
```

I corrected this by

```
Session["name"] = lblName.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question *where* you are trying to access `Session`, but it is available from any code running in the web worker process ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523995/453277)). However, I prefer to put email logic in a separate class or even separate project.

The class can then take the input values as strings, or a type that represents your data.

```
// good
public void SendMail( string name, string address, etc etc )
{
   // mail code here
}

// better
public void SendMail( UserInfo info )
{

}

// best
public void SendMail( UserInfo info, string template )
{
   // insert the user values into a template of some sort...no hardcoding format/HTML
}
```

Regarding `Environment.NewLine`. Your string name is `htmlBody`, which implies you are sending an HTML email. You should use the appropriate markup instead of a newline.

Comment: I have revised my code in the question if it makes a bit more sense. I understand your approach however I'd like to know if it is possible to attempt this the way I have tried it ?

Comment: Yes, that code should work just fine (assuming session is enabled and there are corresponding values).