# Creating a Session

Tags: c#

I am beginner in web development. So please understand me.
I want to create a session or routing using c# just like in php.
so this is the sample logic.

```
if (SESSIONHasValue = True){
//The User can Access the whole website;
}else{
//Maintain to LOGIN PAGE of the Website;
}
```

I want to create a functionality that will redirect the user in login form even if the user type the address of the index page in address bar of the chrome. 
I have seen this question just like mine, but is this the same functionality that i needed? [Create session in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523931/create-session-in-c-sharp)

If you can teach me how to create with this. please help.

regards

Comment: *I want to create a functionality that will redirect the user in login form even if the user type the address of the index page in address bar of the chrome.* actually, i think its better off to use [ASP Membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-membership-provider) for this. may we know your .net version for the project and is it mvc? [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-membership-provider/) seems to be good.

Comment: I just downloaded the template I am using in visual studio sir. a bootstrap template for front end.

Comment: @BagusTesa . I will try this sir. and implement the template in ASP.NET

Comment: err, i thought you start the project through Visual Studio.. i remember on the Visual Studio you will be asked for basic features you need such as authentication and such..

Comment: @BagusTesa , That's why sir. Is that even possible sir?? for having a session without using a localStorage?

Comment: sorry, i think we mixed up some terms.. [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and `session` is different. `localStorage` refers to browser feature. while the `session` for this authentication thingy is the one stored on your web application and it uses cookies to tell which user which. you can access ASP.Net session using something like `HttpContext.Current.Session["some-name-for-your-session"]`. hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

I will show you a very basic example of using `Session` in .NET MVC. You would first have to setup your login model which is basically the fields that you will ask a user to input during the login process. In my case, I am assuming the basic properties which is `username` and `password`:

```
namespace MyExample.Models

public class LoginRequestModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you show your `Login` page to the user, you will pass these model properties to the View. I prefer to use a strongly typed Model-View architecture but you can use other methods like AJAX or FormData to process your form variables to your controller. Now in my `Login` method under `Login` controller, I pass my model like this:

```
using MyExample.Models

namespace MyExample.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Login()
      {
       return View(new LoginRequestModel());
      }
    }
}
```

Notice the namespace that I have put my `LoginRequestModel` class in. You would require to declare this namespace in your controller otherwise you will get an error. Getting to our program, the above method will initialize a new instance of the `LoginRequestModel` and send it to your View where you will be able to bind it to your HTML using `@Html` helper extensions. These come under the `Razor` syntax and are pretty good in handling your form.

Now in order to access your Model in your View, follow these steps:

```
@using MyExample.Models
@model LoginRequestModel

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Your scripts and associated links go in this section -->
</head>
<body>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new {role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @id = "exampleInputUsername", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Enter User ID", @autocomplete = "off" })
   </div>

   <div>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @id = "exampleInputPassword", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Enter Password", @autocomplete = "off", @type = "password" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
 }
</body>
</html>
```

This would create a View with two input text boxes and a submit button. The text boxes are binded to your Model properties `UserName` and `Password`.Now if you will notice this line: `Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Login", FormMethod.Post,`, this tells the form to be sent to `Authenticate` method of your `Login` controller using a POST request. Also if you will observe the line: `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks). This will basically prevent any CSRF attacks on your form by validating a token. You can add `JQuery` validation and style your View with `CSS` as per your need.

The main part comes here now. When you fill out this form and hit submit, the routing will search for a `Authenticate` method in your `Login` controller. Therefore we need to create this method inside our controller.

```
using MyExample.Models
using System.Net.Http;
using System;

namespace MyExample.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Login()
      {
       return View(new LoginRequestModel());
      }

     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult Authenticate(LoginRequestModel loginRequest)
     {
       //Apply your authentication logic here
       bool result = someMethodToAuthenticate(loginRequest)
        if(result==true)
         {
          //Setup your session variables here
          Session["UserName"] = loginRequest.UserName;
          Session["TimeLoggedIn"] = DateTime.Now;
          return RedirectToAction("View Where You Want To Redirect", "Controller Where the View is");
         }
        else
         {
           ViewBag.setError = "Invalid login credentials supplied";
           return View("InvalidLogin");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice that I have imported the namespace `System.Net.Http` which contains your Session  object for the current HTTP request. After your write your authentication logic, based on your outcome you can setup your session variables as shown above. You can use these variables anywhere in the life cycle of the program as long as your don't destroy them. You can access your session variable as: `string loggedInUser=Session["UserName"];`. In order to destroy your session variables, you could do something like:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
 {
   Session.Abandon();
   Session.Clear();
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
 }
```

You can also remove a particular session variable like: `Session.Remove("UserName");`

In order to check for your session, you can do something like:

```
public ActionResult SessionCheck()
 {
   string message = string.Empty;
   if (Session["UserName"] == null)
    {
      message = "Session expired. Please Login again";
    }
    return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

You can check for this method throughout your program using `AJAX` or you could use [SessionState](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/controlling-session-behavior-in-Asp-Net-mvc/).

AJAX Example:

```
function IsSessionActive()
{
    var url ="/Login/SessionCheck";
    var param = {};
    param = JSON.stringify(param);
    var result = getResultPost(url, param);
    if (result != "")
    {
        alert("Session has expired, Please login again");
        return true;
    }
}

function getResultPost(url, param) {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: param,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            result = data; 
        },
        error: function (e) {             
            result = "Error";
        }          
    }); 
    return result;
}
```

And finally call this in your View like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (IsSessionActive()) return false;
})
```

Cheers.